# Ad-Blocker that Downloads the page and then sets the ad to "hidden"

Tags: ad-blocker

I was looking at the way pages detect ad-Blockers...

Basically they check if the page was fully loaded or your browser "skipped" something.

I was wondering if there is an adblocker extension, which would download the page fully and THEN make the browser simply not display the ads.

Like, the ads will be downloaded, OK. Just the browser won't render them at all.

This way the JavaScripts which test if the page got fully loaded will be OK and won't ever know the browser is refusing to display the ads. To them everything will be OK. After all, the page got fully loaded.

Why not simply block JavaScript, you say?

Because I have found sites that gate their content behind the very scripts that test for Ad Blockers, so if you disable those scripts, the site breaks and you don't get access to the content.

That's what I came up with - an Ad Blocker that merely hides the ads while still downloading the complete page so the "guarding" JavaScripts will be happy.

Is this possible?

Does it exist?

Can it be done?